# How to determine if a Polygon is inside another Polygon's hole

Tags: geometry, gis-principle, de-9im

Given two valid polygons `P` and `Q`, what's the cheapest / fastest way to determine:

If polygon `Q` is inside one of polygon `P`'s holes (interior rings), or vice versa. (see illustration below)

To the best of my knowledge, the DE-9IM predicates don't directly help here, since the polygons are disjoint (`FF2FF1212`) according to the matrix, so checks for containment, intersection, crossing, and within aren't useful.
The best I've come up with is:

- check whether the polygons intersect

  - if they don't, construct polygons from their bounding boxes, then check whether `P_bbox` contains `Q_bbox`, or vice versa.
  - One polygon's bounding box will always have to be strictly smaller than the other.

But I'm wondering whether this might catch some other arrangement that I haven't thought of.

[image]

Comment: The small polygon can be outside of the big circle, on a "corner" of the bounding box (so outside but BB is contained)

Comment: Is the "linearly separable" question always trivially "no" given the "Given two valid polygons **arranged like this** (polygon Q inside P's ring)" condition. A polygon inside another polygon can't be linearly separable.

Comment: @spacedman Yes, I'm trying to ensure that two polygons aren't linearly separable, but that this condition derives from this particular arrangement.

Comment: Then no, two polygons arranged like this (one inside another) can't possibly be linearly separable. Is your question really "How can I tell if one polygon is inside another?"

Comment: @Spacedman No, because if that were the case then a simple containment check would be enough, but it correctly returns `false` in this case (which you can verify using GEOS and presumably JTS). My question is really "Given two polygons, how can I tell if one is contained inside the *ring* of the other.

Comment: How about: "How can I tell if polygon A is completely in a hole of polygon B?"

Comment: @Spacedman Yep that's pretty clear. See latest edit.

Comment: Does of both the polygon sets fullyf the "area positive" ring orientation schema?

Comment: @huckfinn I'd certainly be interested in an answer that assumes they do.

Answer (score 4):

Since you are dealing with holes, you could replace such polygons with a filled version. If the polygon has an inner ring, take the outter ring and create a new temporary polygon, then check if it contains others. If yes, using the original polygon, check that it doesn't intersect the smaller one

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if it is the cheapest way, because you have to calculate M Winding numbers of (P) for N points in Q.

The [windings number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winding_number) in conjunction with the orientation of the ring could give you a clue if something is inside or outside.

I use this technique, if I want to determin if a **point** is inside or outside of a polygon constellation. You calculate the angles between your object in/out of the polygon and build the sum of these angles for each ring.

Here I illustrated the matter with positive or negative angles...

[image]

To prevent the usage of things like **~ 360°** or **~0°** only the signs of the around running angles are registered.

Sketch of the algorithm:

If the point set of Q not laying in P (abort condition...) as
calculated as the sum of winding numbers S for each polygon of P with:

WS = SUM (sgn[i] * S[i]);

while:

```
 sgn[i] = 1  if it is an outer and 

 sgn[i] = -1 if it is an inner ring of P;
```

You will get a result with:

if the sum for each vertex is 0 your object is outside,

if the sum > 0 it is inside.

Comment: Have you just described a point-in-polygon algorithm? I'm not sure how that helps.

Comment: @Spacedman Sorry to be unclear but, ... you have to calculate M Winding numbers of P for **N points in Q** and the question if the thingy is complete in-/ outside.